# ::SendMessage(apphwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) return 0

Tags: c++, window, sendmessage

I use `::CreateProcess`  to create a subprocess, and use `::EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, processInfo.dwThreadId)` to get the subprocess's window handle, assign this handle to a global variable `apphwnd`, then I use `length = ::SendMessage(apphwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);` but the length is sometimes is zero.

Why is my subprocess's window handle valid but the `windowText` sometimes has no value?  When can I operate on the window handle correctly after `CreateProcess` is done?

Here is `EnumWindowsProc` code :

```
HWND apphwnd;

int CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM param)
{
    CString str;
    DWORD pID;
    DWORD TpID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pID);//get process id

    std::string hwndProcessName = GetProcessNameByHandle(hwnd);

    if (TpID == (DWORD)param)
    {
        apphwnd = hwnd;//hwnd is the window handle
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is my `StartProcess` function code:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION StartProcess(LPCTSTR program, LPCTSTR args, int sleepTime = 500, STARTUPINFO *pstartupInfo = NULL, DWORD dwCreationFlags = 0, bool isWaitInput = false)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    ::ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    if(::CreateProcess(program, (LPTSTR)args,
        NULL,  // process security
        NULL,  // thread security
        FALSE, // no inheritance
        dwCreationFlags,     // no startup flags
        NULL,  // no special environment
        NULL,  // default startup directory
        &startupInfo,
        &processInfo))
    {
        Sleep(500);
        if (true)
        {
            WaitForInputIdle(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        }

        apphwnd = NULL;

        hProcess = processInfo.hProcess;
        while(true)
        {
            ::EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, processInfo.dwThreadId);//Iterate all windows
            if (apphwnd)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } /* success */
    return processInfo;
}
```

Here is what Spy++ shows:

[image: spy++ window picture]

Comment: It is possible that you are detecting the window before its title is assigned. Or that you are detecting the wrong window altogether if the process creates multiple windows

Comment: EnumWindowsProc  help me find the correct window of the process, so i can't be wrong. I  get the window titile in a loop , sometimes it always be null.

Comment: "*EnumWindowsProc help me find the correct window of the process, so i can't be wrong*" - sure you can. Your enum callback is checking only the process ID to find the window you are interested in. The process ID alone MAY NOT be good enough, depending on which UI framework the app uses. Try checking the window's class name, too. It would be helpful if you provided a screenshot from Spy++ or similar to showing the actual window you are interested in finding.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau, I have post the spy++ screenshot.

Comment: after I `createprocess `(C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe),  sometimes I acctually do not get the window titile.

Comment: in your screenshot, #2 is not a top level window, so `EnumWindows()` won't see it, only is parent dialog #1. You will have to detect that dialog in your enum callback so you can enumerate its child windows. #3 is a top level window, though. Note also that your `while` loop is not taking into account that the spawned process may terminate while you are still looping, or that you may be spawning a loader that then spawns the real app you are interested in as a separate process of its own. IIRC, that is actually the case with the latest MSPaint version as it is now a UWP app

Comment: my purpose is to embed exe file into my #1 window. #2 is also created by `createprocess`,  next  use `EnumWindow()` get the window handle,  at last use `SetParent` make #2 be #1's child window.   #3 is doing the same way.  #2 always successfully embeded, but #3 some times failed.  so I confused why the window handle of createprocess (C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe)   is not correct

Comment: #3 related spawn process does not terminated, the spawned window handle call `SendMessage` get nothing

Comment: "*my purpose is to embed exe file into my #1 window*" - [don't do that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) especially if you don't own the program you are spawning

Comment: `SetParent` works fine when I embed #2 (another exe  created by `CreateProcess` ) into #1 window.  I have red the article you post. It tells that technically legal, but difficult to manage.  `Sharing variables within a process is much easier than sharing variables across processes` ,    exe Created by `CreateProcess`  and #1 process are  within a process or across process ?